# Mysql - How can I transfer data from one table to another on a specific day and time in the week, every week?

Tags: mysql, database, datatable

I want to transfer data from one table to another table on a specific day (Friday at 20:00) every week. I also want to reset the data from the first table every Sunday.

When I run this line it sends the correct data to the right table (table1).

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table1 (Name, Email, Phone, Work, Week)
    VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$phone', '$work', '$weekNumber')";
```

When I run this line it sends one random row from table1 to table2. It will not store any of the new data in table1, only use data which is already stored in table1.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table2 (Name, Email, Work, Week) SELECT Name, Email, Work, Week FROM table1 Where Week = ('$weekNumber') ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
```

All of this code is written in a php-file and i view the tables in phpMyadmin.

Any sql-gurus out there with suggestions on how I can make data from table1 transferred to table2 every Friday at 20:00? Appreciate it in advance. Keep in mind i'm new to writing sql-code and just started working with databases this week, therefore I would really appreciate specific code-examples instead of general information on how I can perceive my objective. Combined would be best though.

Comment: Can you point out, what your actual question is? Do you need general optimization advice (design, architecture, performance?), or do you run into errors, or does your code not do what you want? Please try to be a bit more specific, then you'll likely get more helpful answers ;-)

Comment: Thanks Stefan. I'm new here and appreciate your guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily with event scheduler in MySQL

https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-create-mysql-events/

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers/working-mysql-scheduled-event/

As as example, you could use the following to do a specific task everyday:

```
 DELIMITER ;; 
    CREATE EVENT UpdateData ON SCHEDULE EVERY DAY STARTS '2016-10-10 00:00:00' -- This is scheduled to start from '2016-10-10' and updates data every day 
      DO BEGIN 
        UPDATE table1 SET Status = 1 WHERE Status = 0; 
        UPDATE table2 SET Status = 1 WHERE Status = 0;
     END;; 
 DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Okay, i'll try wrapping my head around MySQL Event Scheduler. I'll consider it my final solution as other people also refer to it as the only way to work with my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

@Willi W Try this

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table2 (Name, Email, Work, Week) SELECT Name, Email, Work, Week FROM table1 as a Where Week = ('$weekNumber') and NOT EXISTS (Select * FROM table2 as b where b.Name=a.Name and b.Email=a.Email and b.Work=a.Work and b.Week=a.Week) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
```

This will insert unique data in table2.

Comment: The form which i'm working on wouldn't submit when i tried this code.

Comment: @Willi W please explain the reason why you said so. which type of form you are using?

Comment: A basic html-form submitted by users. 

    <form id="myform" name="theform" class="group" onsubmit="event.preventDefault();mySubmitFunction();">

Comment: So what's the problem in above query. Please explain in details because i am not getting what you need?

Comment: I need to create a sql-code which will transfer data from one table to another every Friday at 20:00. At the moment my code submits the data to the correct database and table, but I have created another table where I want data from the first table to appear/transferred every Friday at 20:00.

Comment: If you want to make a query to work on specific time, then you must use MySQL event scheduler or cron job.

Comment: Okay, I just really hoped I could work with some if/else -magic.

Comment: And btw @manish , I got the form to submit just fine with you're code-example. I just forgot to retype a table name. My bad. Thanks, all tough it really didn't help find a solution for my original problem.